# Getting Column number from result of a match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Index/Match where it returns the address of cell.  I was wondering how I could extract just the column number from that?

=CELL("Address",INDEX(Sheet1!E3:AA3,MATCH(TODAY()+1,Sheet1!E3:AA3,0)))

this is my lookup and it properly returns the value. Just struggling to extract the column?

Comment: `=COLUMN(INDIRECT(your_formula`))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your Index formula into a column() function

```
=COLUMN(INDEX(Sheet1!E3:AA3;MATCH(TODAY()+1;Sheet1!E3:AA3;0)))
```

[image]